# Exporting post content from wordpress using WP All Export and wpautop() php function to include paragraph tags

Tags: plugins

I have exported my post content from wordpress using WP All Export plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/, however the content of my posts has been exported as HTML but is missing paragraph tags causing all the text to run together when I import it to my new website.

I have read this guide: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/export/pass-data-through-php-functions/

And would like to apply the solution described here: https://codelight.eu/exporting-wordpress-posts-and-pages-with-paragraph-tags-included/ when exporting the Content field.

However, my knowledge of PHP is poor at best.

Below is a screenshot of what I believe I need to do. Will this work? I can't test it as I don't yet have the full version of the plugin yet and I don't want to waste money purchasing the full version of WP All Export yet in case this won't work.

I don't want to use this solution as I need to leave the existing wordpress website as is. [How do I add paragraph tags to all of my posts after relying on wpauto?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6844/how-do-i-add-paragraph-tags-to-all-of-my-posts-after-relying-on-wpauto) - but what I do want to do is what this post suggests at the end: "apply the autop filter in your export routine"

Can anyone please provide some guidance?

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't need most of that code. Just write `wpautop` in the text box between the `<?php` tags.